# Lambda expression with two navigation properties

Tags: c#, lambda, wcf-ria-services

I have a situation where I am calling an entity and putting in two includes in the ria services call.

```
public IQueryable<Position> GetPositions(int programID)
{
    return _positionRepository.All()
                .Where(x => x.ProgramID == programID)
                .Include("RecPositions.Person");
}
```

Id like to get a handle on the Person entity on the front end. I have this working..the code below gives me a handle on the recPositions and in the intellisence I can see the Person object. id like to abstract that entity.

```
var test = _allRec.Select(x => x.RecPositions).ToList();
```

test now has my RecPosition...but i want to know how to write a lambda express so i can get a handle on the person object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this..does anyone have any objections to this or a better way..

```
var test = _allRec.SelectMany(x => x.RecPositions)
                  .Select(p => p.Person)
                  .ToList();
```

this seems to give me what I want.

Comment: I'm guessing that you could benefit from throwing a .Distinct() in before the final .ToList(), but otherwise looks good.